# Placeholder control that includes an item gets index out of range

Tags: c#, asp.net, indexoutofrangeexception, asp.net-placeholder

I have a Placeholder where a table is dynamically added on page load (everything loads fine and I can see control[0] when debugging without a problem.  When button is clicked to reset the form, I try to access that table at control[0] and get "index out of range".  I have researched quite a bit and can not find why that is happening.

Here is the code when page loads:

```
    private void LoadTable()
    {
        Table oTable = new Table();

        //gather table row and cell info here - table loads fine on page

        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(oTable);
    }
```

This code fires when button is clicked:

```
    private void ResetForm()
    {
        //clear out textboxes and dropdown lists

        Table oTable = new Table();
        oTable = (Table)PlaceHolder1.Controls[0];  // this is where problem occurs
    }
```

and the HTML:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

I hope that it isn't something obvious that I'm missing, since I'm still fairly new to programming.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a `IsPostBack` control for `LoadTable()`method in `PageLoad` event?

Comment: Where are you calling ResetForm()?

Comment: Actually that LoadTable() method was in if (!Page.IsPostBack)... I moved it out and that did the trick.  Thank you!  Can you explain further why the PlaceHolder1 loses its data on PostBack?  I'll accept your answer if you provide one.

Comment: @Kami on button_Click

Comment: On Postback the aspx page re-renders and all controls are reset. if you want to keep the data in your place holder put it in an Ajax UpdatePanel.

Comment: I am confused. You did call the LoadTable method in if(!IsPostBack) but you moved out and problem solved. Actually I would say that put it in the IsPostBack control.

Comment: Correct - I guess it was losing its data with the PostBack, and the Placeholder didn't reload the table. It is firing on IsPostBack now (the LoadTable method), so everything is working.